# Seesion data is overriding after logging into replica of first package with different DB

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have a CI(codeigniter) package,when i logged into that package i am setting some session variables with Db values .
And then i logged in to copy of first package which have different DB.After logging into this 2nd package in the same browser with another tab the session variables are overriding.
so when i refresh the first package the 2nd package data is displaying because of override d session data.how to overcome this issue without changing the session variable names.Please help me on this if is there any solution .
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of encryption key in the config value.
$config['encryption_key'] 
Check whether both has same encryption key.

Comment: After changing also same thing is happening.

Comment: Then try changing the cookie name instead
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session'; to something like
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_sessions';

Comment: even though i have changed the session cookie name the same data is loading after reloading the first package.

Comment: Did you have changed in both package or a single package? 
Try changing it only on one of the package and left other as default.

Comment: i have changed in only one package.and also tried by changing in both packages but it is overriding again.